# Command works in terminal but not as service

Tags: linux, systemd

Many of these problems are because of a wrong path. This could not have been my problem as I put the absoulute path there.
When I started the service, it always displayed "inactive (dead)" even though the start was successful

My .service file was the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=hd-idle - spin down idle hard disks
Documentation=man:hd-idle(1)
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
Group=root
WorkingDirectory=/root
#EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/hd-idle
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/hd-idle -i 10
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my solution coincidentally in another [StackExchange Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38377069/14236974).

It was to set the `RemainAfterExit` tag to yes in the service category:

```
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

The reason for this as I understood it is that the command executes, but changes a system flag for another program to change. When I don't set the `RemainAfterExit` tag, my program only exits without doing anything, which leads it to just don't do anything in my case.